# Combining 2 RealmList object in realm android

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

How to use realm relationships using 2 RealmList, here the example.

Class Menu

```
    public class Menu extends RealmObject {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("module")
    private String module;

    @SerializedName("controller")
    private String controller;

    @SerializedName("parent_module")
    private String parentModule;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private Boolean status;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getModule() {
        return module;
    }

    public void setModule(String module) {
        this.module = module;
    }

    public String getController() {
        return controller;
    }

    public void setController(String controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public String getParentModule() {
        return parentModule;
    }

    public void setParentModule(String parentModule) {
        this.parentModule = parentModule;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Class Privilege

```
  public class Privilege extends RealmObject {

    private String module;

    public String getModule() {
        return module;
    }

    public void setModule(String module) {
        this.module = module;
    }

}
```

and i'm using this method to save them.

```
@Override
public void saveMenuPrivilege(RealmList<Menu> menu, RealmList<Privilege> privileges) {

}
```

now what makes me confuse is, there is a condition where if the module in class Menu has the same module in class Privilege, then set the active field for that module in class Menu to be "true". How to do that? or i'm doing it wrong using the code above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All ready have the answer, just testing all by myself. :D